# как правильно формировать выражение с include для div в javascript

Tags: javascript, include

Доброе время суток,

Мой код:

```js
var citydiv = document.getElementById('cityimg');
citydiv.innerHTML = '<img src=<!--#include file="img/citys/city10.txt"--> id="city_data" />';
```

Получаю такой результат:

```html
<div id="cityimg">
  <img src="<!--#include" file="img/citys/city10.txt" --=""> id="city_data" />
</div>
```

Как сделать чтобы получился правильный html и получил результат ?

Comment: Што такое `img/citys/city10.txt`?

Comment: Это изображение в base64.

Comment: `<img src="img/citys/city10.txt"> id="city_data" />` попробуйте

Comment: Первый код в .js -файле?

Comment: Так ошибку не выдает: <img src="img/citys/city10.txt"> id="city_data" />   но изображение не отображается.

Comment: Код я проверил в html: <div class="cityimg">
    <img src=<!--#include file="img/citys/city10.txt"--> id="city_data" />
</div>

Comment: В браузерном js вообще нет такой вещи как include.

Comment: Попробуйте <img data="img/citys/city10.txt" id="city_data" />

Comment: Но мне надо будет его временами менять динамический, поэтому не могу жестко прописать в html.

Comment: Может что-то подобное: `<div>
    <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>`

Comment: Менять то просто: `elem.src="anotherImg.png"`

Comment: Лучше либо текстом пишите (прямо `...innerHTML = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVB...`), либо png/jpg/gif/svg картинку ставьте -проще

Comment: У меня содержимое city10.txt такое же как в Вашем примере: data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

Comment: Сразу текстом нельзя, требование брать текст из файла.

Comment: так вы php делаете или js?

Comment: в JavaScript делаю

Comment: в консоли.exe, консоли браузера, файле рядом с html-файлом, втутру <script>  html-файла?

Comment: нет, javascript вызывается из html, <script data-main="js/reports.js" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>

Comment: Есть условие задания?

Comment: В HTML странице есть контейнер div с id=cityimg. Также есть файл city10.txt в котором изображение в формате base64. С помощью JS, необходимо отобразить в виде изображения в контейнере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил пока таким методом, работает:

```js
var citydiv = document.getElementById('cityimg');
$.ajax({
    url: 'img/citys/city10.txt',
    type: 'get',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
  citydiv.innerHTML = '<img src="'+result+'" id="city_data" />';
    }
});
```